# C# - Is there any standard way of converting a string to json

Tags: c#, json, string

I have a set of text files, each of their own loose structure. I have written a class to edit them so they are more uniform in structure - 1 line per JSON node etc.

The current format of each file is as follows

```
Filename
parentNodeName1:value1, value2, value3
parentNodeName2:value1, value2
parentNodeName3:value1
parentNodeName4:value1, value2, value3
```

I want to put them into JSON format. Is there a well used library or procedure to do this?

Comment: you can try to achieve this with JavaScriptSerializer: it's found in System.Web.Script.Serialization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the [`JavaScriptSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`DataContractJsonSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) class that can generate JSON for you.

A nice article on the more complex `DataContractJsonSerializer` can be found at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179(v=vs.110).aspx). You also might want to look into [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json), which has a better performance and is easier in use.

Comment: Does JSON.NET not require me to already have my text parsed to an object? I need the JSON to simply read a string with an unknown structure and attempt to JSON-ise it

Comment: Serializing a string into JSON is fairly simple and can be done with `string.Format` too. This will only work well when you have an object which has a structure to save, not just one value.

Answer (score 0):

for me [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json) works fine. I think you can do your staff with that without any problems. It has good documentation and support.

Answer (score 0):

Others used the standard classes so I will also answer with a different twist.  If you have very large files FastJSON does seem to be much faster.  But you can't beat a standard package if you don't need the speed.  https://fastjson.codeplex.com/